# CMS or E-Commerce tool for virtual product search

Tags: database, drupal, magento, joomla, e-commerce

I am trying to create a site that is more-or-less a directory of products that are available for a free trial.  There are several thousand in my database.  None of what I sell is actually a physical or virtual product.  Basically, my site is an advertising conduit for companies that sell software free trials.  The customer finds the product and they are then handed off to a sign-up form, which is then conveyed to the publisher.  I require strong search capabilities with filtering, faceted navigation (sometimes referred to as Layered Navigation), and fast search.

I have run into a brick wall several times with CMS's, including Joomla, Drupal, Business Catalyst, Magento, and a few others.  The problem is that the programs I've used are geared to E-Commerce applications where price, manufacturers, shipping, etc. are important variables.  I don't need that.  But, I do want to organize these items by categories and facets, providing a category-driven search experience.  I also like how forms, newsletters, CMS, categorization, product uploads, attributes, etc. are built in.  Templating needs to be relatively easy.

I don't have the talent to construct everything from scratch.

Does anybody have good suggestions?

Comment: Is your site linking to SaaS type sites with free trials or downloadable software?

Answer (score 2):

Magento is ideally suited to this task, and it is relatively straight-forward to disable the price/checkout components. I know of a number of sites that do exactly that, either because they are not ready for eCommerce yet but planning for the future, or never plan to use it. Magento already has the category and product management administration UI built out, is SEO optimized and has the faceted navigation available.

Removing the price and add-to-cart can be as similar as editing the `catalog/product/view.phtml` template and removing the snippets that render those elements.  Likewise from the `catalog/product/list.phtml`.

IMHO, you will find it much less work to disable the unnecessary features from Magento than to recreate them in a different framework.